# Gridview Button Adapter context menu

Tags: android, gridview, button, adapter

I have a phrasebook, with the ability to save the sample to SD. I use a Gridview set up with the following code in place for the button adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
        final Sample sample = board.getSamples().get(position);

        if (sample != null) {

            Button button = new Button(context);
            button.setText(sample.getName());
            button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 
            button.setTextSize(12);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context.play(sample);
                }

            });

            // TODO Implement this correctly.
             button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
             public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

             return context.saveToSD(sample);


             }
             });

            return button;
        }
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "No sample at position "
                + position);
    }

    return null;
}
```

I am looking to integrate a context menu here on a Long press, to give the option of where to save the sample. I don't seem to be able to register the button for the context menu within this method (ie registerForContextMenu(button), as it gives me errors.

I am a bit stumped here, any pointers would be a great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I take it that this is an old post but I came across it today as I was looking for an answer on the same topic. Like the question here I have a grid of items and wanted to show a context menu on long click.

I am not using a contextmenu but instead I am using an AlertDialog.

```
gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            showOptionsMenu(position);
            return true;
        }

    });

public void showOptionsMenu(int position)
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("test").setCancelable(true).setItems(R.array.myOptions,
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                       //take actions here according to what the user has selected
                   }
             }
    )
.show();
}
```

Hope this helps.